# Browsing files via Bluetooth doesn't work

Tags: 11.10, bluetooth

How can I browse files using Bluetooth in Ubuntu 11.10? I get paired perfectly, but I can't browse files. Nothing happens.

I asked about it before. People recommended install Blueman. I did but Blueman didn't work either.

Bluetooth worked perfectly in Ubuntu 11.04. The same cell phone I use today I could get paired and Browse Files.

20 minutes ago I was using Ubuntu 11.04 Live CD and used the Bluetooth and was perfectly (I get paired and Browse Files). I took a screenshot to show you.

I can't believe that in a old system (11.04) was perfectly but the evolution (11.10) is a regression about Bluetooth. Why?

Please, how can I solve this problem (Browse Files) on Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: I would suggest you report this as a bug.

Comment: I use to see a lot of people reporting this bug but nothing happen until now.

Comment: Still a problem in 12.04.  I have reported this as a bug, please vote it up:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-bluetooth/+bug/987986

Comment: This bug persists in 12.04 also as browsing files on a device, send a file from a mobile and vice-versa doesn't work. Really a bummer. :(

Comment: If you have an Android phone. Install "wifi file transfer" in the apps store and run. You should be able to transfer files using a browser interface. It works for me... You will be requied to type in the ip address of the phone in your internet browser. this is all explained on the device once started...

Answer (score 3):

the problem is probably in [some kernel/gvfs changes](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/899858) that caused regression in bluetooth operation.

A workaround that has been [posted in some places](http://ubuntu-answers.blogspot.com/2011/11/bluetooth-on-ubuntu-1110.html) is to manually mount devices via the OBEX filesystem, as follows:

- `sudo apt-get install obexfs` (only needed once)
- `hcitool scan` -- will return list of bluetooth devices with their addresses, looking like `8F:77:...:16`
- have a directory ready to mount device onto, e.g. `~/Device`
- `obexfs -b 8F:77:..:16 /Device`

Then, the device's files can be browsed over bluetooth under the Device folder.

To unmount when finished with browsing the device, use

- `fusermount -u ~/Device`

My guess is that the problem will be corrected in some not-so-distant update.

Comment: For the "hcitool" scan to work, I had to put my phone in discoverable mode.  Instead, you can also get the Hex address from the Unity bluetooth settings dialog. For Android I needed to enable the FTP server checkbox under bluetooth settings for this to work.

Comment: @HDave No FTP option on Samsung Exhibit. Looking into it...

Answer (score 1):

Premek Brada is Right...

Look here too:
http://www.worldofnubcraft.com/1767/a-bluetooth-quick-fix-hack-for-ubuntu-11-10/

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart bluetooth with

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Comment: It's `service`, not 'services'. To short for editing.

Comment: if something is wrong, fix it, please. еnglish is not my native language

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with sharing files from a bluetooth device with ubuntu. I have tried a work around using my Android phone. Install "wifi file transfer" in the apps store and run. You should be able to transfer files using a browser interface. It works for me... You will be requied to type in the ip address of the phone in your internet browser. this is all explained on the device once started.